# Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query shown here is returning multiple rows in the `Description` column and causing the error mentioned in the title.

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT 
    T0.[TransId], T0.[Account], T0.[ShortName], T0.[ContraAct], 
    CASE
        WHEN T0.[TransType] = '18 '
           THEN (SELECT Description FROM PCH1 
                 WHERE DocEntry = T0.CreatedBy AND AcctCode = T0.Account)
           ELSE T0.[LineMemo]
    END AS Description,
    T0.[Ref3Line], T0.[TransType], T0.[RefDate], 
    T0.[CreatedBy], T0.[BaseRef] 
FROM 
    JDT1 T0 
WHERE 
    T0.[Account] = '630000'
```

Comment: The error message can't really be any more clear.  The subquery in your larger query above sometimes returns more than one value, whereas the `CASE` expression requires only scalar (single) values must follow `THEN` and `ELSE`.  Please add sample data to your question for best results here.

Comment: `SELECT Description FROM PCH1 WHERE DocEntry = T0.CreatedBy AND AcctCode = T0.Account ` returning more than one values is the root cause. use top(1) will solve this. hope this will help you

Comment: The error is really clear.  What you want to do is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your subquery return multiple records at

```
(SELECT Description FROM PCH1 
             WHERE DocEntry = T0.CreatedBy AND AcctCode = T0.Account)
```

You can try to add the **SELECT TOP 1** for your

```
SELECT 
    T0.[TransId], T0.[Account], T0.[ShortName], T0.[ContraAct], 
    CASE
        WHEN T0.[TransType] = '18 '
           THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Description FROM PCH1 
                 WHERE DocEntry = T0.CreatedBy AND AcctCode = T0.Account)
           ELSE T0.[LineMemo]
    END AS Description,
    T0.[Ref3Line], T0.[TransType], T0.[RefDate], 
    T0.[CreatedBy], T0.[BaseRef] 
FROM 
    JDT1 T0 
WHERE 
    T0.[Account] = '630000'
```

Hope it can be useful
by GoDevStack

Comment: But a `SELECT TOP (n)` *without* an explicit `ORDER BY` is kinda useless - which "top 1" row do you get ? You need to **explicitly define** an order to get what you really need....